# How do I load the ChromeDriver binary from the classpath?

Tags: java, webdriver, classpath, selenium-chromedriver

A number of sources make reference to loading the ChromeDriver binary from the classpath, but I haven't worked out how to do it if the binary is not in the classpath root.

To specify the path for the binary it seems that you have to set a system property "webdriver.chrome.driver". First I tried:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "drivers/Chrome/chromedriver.exe");
```

But I got an error, and it seems it was looking for the driver in the location `"C:\<working directory of my application process>\drivers\Chrome\chromedriver.exe"`. Here the working directory was actually the directory where my source code is stored.

Then I tried:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/drivers/Chrome/chromedriver.exe");
```

However the same thing happened - this time it was looking in `"C:\drivers\Chrome\chromedriver.exe"`.

How do I get ChromeDriver to look for the ChromeDriver binary on the classpath when using the "webdriver.chrome.driver" property or any other way of configuring it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ultimately, I found that `ChromeDriver` doesn't support classpath-relative access to its binary. However, you can convert the classpath-relative string to a system path and then directly load it, bypassing the system property.

```
URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(classpathRelativeLocation);
File file = new File(url.getFile()); // Strangely, URL.getFile does not return a File
ChromeDriverService.Builder bldr = (new ChromeDriverService.Builder())
                                   .usingDriverExecutable(file)
                                   .usingAnyFreePort();
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(bldr.build());
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `ChromeDriver(ChromeDriverService service)` constructor is deprecated in Selenium3 (as of today, it still works, who knows how long...). Consider this example for "proper" usage: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeDriver.html

Comment: @Siaynoq From this link I see `ChromeDriver​(Capabilities capabilities)` is deprecated and `ChromeDriver(ChromeDriverService service)` not

Answer (score 2):

If you have the driver viz. `chromedriver.exe` on your classpath, you can use the classloader to load the resource and then get the path to it. The same can be passed in as the second argument to setProperty. For e.g. I have the file `chromedriver.exe` placed in *Java Build Path source* folder `/src/main/resources`

I am then able to use the below code to pick the driver from the classpath

```
public class App 
{
private static final String CHROME_DRIVER_PATH=App.class.getClassLoader().getResource("chromedriver.exe").getPath(); 
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws InterruptedException
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", CHROME_DRIVER_PATH);
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.close();        
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

In my opinion, it should work with the following full path:

```
 System.SetProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", @"D:/drivers/Chrome/chromedriver.exe");
 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();              
 driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

I hope that that this helps you!

Comment: That's a system path, not a classpath.